# Accessing Vuex in v-bind

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue.js, vuex

I would like to access a value from a `Vuex` store module within `v-bind`.

```
<input @blur="validate_field" 
       name="firstName" 
       placeholder="First Name" 
       :class="{fail: this.$store.state.formStore.signupForm.errors.firstName}"
/>
```

This throws the following error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'signupForm' of undefined`

I have tried adding the following:

```
computed: {
  ...mapState({
    signupForm: state => state.formStore.signupForm
  })
}
```

And replacing the failing line with:

```
:class="{fail: signupForm.errors.firstName}"
```

as well as a panoply of other things, to no avail. Any ideas?

EDIT: Here is my store:

```
const state = {
  // data
  formStore: {
    // data
    signupForm: {
    // data
      errors: {
        // NO data
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You'll want to start using [Vuex's getters](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/getters.html).

Comment: signupForm is an Object in your store?  You need to reference it via 'state', like so:  this.$store.state.formStore...    But, that may not work, depending on how that Object was created. It needs to be reactive, and you'll probably want to use a getter for the specific property you're after

Comment: @ceejayoz wouldn't getters seem like overkill for this scenario? All I want to do is update the class when the value changes in state

Comment: @wes right, but that seems redundant given I'm using `mapState`

Comment: @softcode IMO, no. That said, `:class="{fail: this.$store.formStore.signupForm.errors.firstName}"` may work if you do `:class="{fail: $store.formStore.signupForm.errors.firstName}"` - `this` is typically omitted in the template.

Comment: @ceejayoz edited, it was actually `state` that was missing between `this.$store` and `formStore`. However as mentioned above it feels needlessly verbose especially since I'm using `mapState`. EDIT nvm that didn't work

Comment: Vue doesn't know if a property of an Object changes, unless you've made it specifically reactive (https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html). So, listening to signupForm will not trigger anything if firstName changes. You could set up your getter to the property you care about:    name: state => state.formStore.signupForm.errors.firstName

Comment: It would probably help to see how your store is set up

Comment: @wes Yeah the doc you shared just clarified it. Will answer my question with the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @wes in the comments for pointing out the doc on reactivity.

[Here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats) the doc says:

> Due to the limitations of modern JavaScript (and the abandonment of
> Object.observe), Vue cannot detect property addition or deletion.

I was dynamically populating the error object. Turns out Vue.js doesn't detect this and as such can't react to it.

With the addition of `firstName`, it works:

```
const state = {
  // data
  formStore: {
    // data
    signupForm: {
    // data
      errors: {
        firstName: ''  <--------
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The lesson is: all properties you expect Vue to react to must be declared explicitly.